Failed to determine the https port for redirect .NET 8 on Linux running in Oracle VirtualBox
My C# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with Swagger works fine on Windows.
However when I run it on Linux in Oracle VirtualBox hosted on my Win10 machine, I see the Swagger UI, but when I try my test "Hello World", it fails.
jounrnalctl -u myapp.service 

reports

Failed to determine the https port for redirecting Net8

My nginx.conf is
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # Enable SSL on port 443
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/dotnet.my.com.au.crt; # Path to your SSL certificate
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/dotnet.my.com.au.key; # Path to your SSL key

        location / {
           proxy_pass https://localhost:5001;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

      
        #ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt; # Path to your SSL certificate
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/nginx-selfsigned.key; # Path to your SSL key

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}

My appsettings.json includes:
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Port": 5001
      }
    }
  },

Update
The error stopped after I published to a folder and copied the files.
I have tried to repeat the issue by copying again from debug but haven't been able to repeat.
